# Keyword for direct passthrough of **kwargs to super().__init__

Tags: python, class

Can there be a "magical keyword" (which obviously only works if no `**kwargs` is specified) so that the `__init__(*args, ***pass_through_kwargs)` so that all unexpected `kwargs` are directly passed through to the `super().__init__`? (in the background and without the users knowledge) This would make the readability much easier and it can be safely ignored by autocomplete and automated documentation.

In the following diagram `Mouse` is ever only instantiated with a `name`. Just to make the `super`-calls down the line work I have to add `**kwargs` (to specify the `number_of_holes` the cheese has) and hand them over by hand. Can't I just tell `Mouse` and `Animal` "Whatever you don't know: just pass it directly down to `super()`"?
[image: Class diagram with red path of <code>super()</code> calls]

Of course you one might want to think about collisions, but I think this might greatly improve the readability of code

Comment: Why to you want to hide it?

Comment: @MegaIng Because the user never needs to include any `kwargs` in the init of `Cheese` and so might just get confused when instantiating it

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your class deps? I don't see why you would want to call two init methods of different classes in the init of another class and not just add them as attributes.

Comment: @jbndlr My class `MickeyMouse` needs to call the init of both `Cheese` and `Mouse`. (This is what we are doing so far). Instead I would like just to call `super().__init__` and let the MRO take care of it. So that `super(Cheese, self).__init__` then calls `Mouse.__init__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to Updated Question

This, indeed, *is* possible. Before providing some code for demonstration, let me just give a few notes:

- This kind of *automagic* attribute access is **really bad style**. You cannot document it, it *will* let people misuse/ignore encapsulation concepts.
- It is not self-explanatory at all; you cannot use duck typing, because suddenly every object can have arbitrary attributes.
- What you really want to do is creating a consistent and understandable design among objects that have a clear focus and bring the corresponding functionality.

However, if you still want to test it, you can just go with `**kwargs` and pass it *up* to the super constructor; it always contains all keyword arguments that are *not* explicitly set in the method signature:

```
def testme(color='red', **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

testme(width=3)

# See that 'color' is not in kwargs dict if running this code:
>>> {'width': 3}
```

This is the case, because explicitly set keyword arguments are assigned to the variable name given in the function signature; the rest is captured in `kwargs`.

This behavior allows you to actually *filter* those keyword arguments in each `__init__` that are *expected*, and pass the rest upwards to the super class' `__init__`:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, num_legs, **kwargs):
        self.num_legs = num_legs

        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            if not hasattr(self, key):
                print(
                    'Generic attribute assignment: {:s} = {:s}'
                    .format(key, str(value)))
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        res = '<Animal ({:s}):\n'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        for key in dir(self):
            if key.startswith('__'):
                continue
            res += '  {:s} = {:s}\n'.format(key, str(getattr(self, key)))
        res += '>'
        return res


class Mouse(Animal):
    def __init__(self, color='gray', **kwargs):
        super(Mouse, self).__init__(4, **kwargs)
        self.color = color


class MickeyMouse(Mouse):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MickeyMouse, self).__init__(color='black', **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mm = MickeyMouse(dog='Pluto')
    print(mm)
```

This will yield:

```
Generic attribute assignment: dog = Pluto
<Animal (MickeyMouse):
  color = black
  dog = Pluto
  num_legs = 4
>
```

The rationale is, that the keyword `'dog'` is never expected in any of the `__init__` methods and thus always remains in the `kwargs`, until the last super class' `__init__` runs through the dict and sets the corresponding attributes. That's where the assignment message is printed. Afterwards, the specialized `__init__` methods set their values (here: `'color'`) and you're done.

Can you please explain your figure? Do arrows represent dependencies, ownerships, inheritance, ...?

## Previous/Outdated Answer

If your class `MickeyMouse` needs to call the init of both `Cheese` and `Mouse`, you need to be sure about their dependencies first.

Constructing a concrete object from a class definition yields a *stateful representation* of that very class. So if you create a `MickeyMouse` object, it may be required that it calls its super class' constructor, for example that one of class `Mouse` -- given `MickeyMouse` inherits from `Mouse`. If you now want the initialization of your `MickeyMouse` also to call the `Cheese` init, it would create a new object of that kind, essentially having two objects at hand: A mouse (i.e. `MickeyMouse`), and a cheese where nobody knows where it came from.

But maybe I still didn't get the application case right. Anyhow, concerning your implementation approach:

### No Method Overloading

As you noticed, the `__init__` method of a class is a single instance (magic) method you *cannot overload*. And since it is not possible by design, you should not try to overload, or even create method-swapping implementations that try to achieve overloading of class methods.

In your example, you state that you want to be able to create instances of a single class using different args and kwargs combinations and to *magically* resolve to the correct handling.

### Possible Ways Out

(1) Use kwargs only:

```
class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self, num_holes=0, weight=None, name=None):
        # Add logic depending on kwargs that are not None
        pass
```

Use it like so:

```
cheddar = Cheese()
gouda = Cheese(num_holes=3)
owned_cheddar = Cheese(name='MickeyMouse')
```

(2) Use static constructor methods.

```
class Cheese(object):
    def __init__(self, num_holes, weight, name):
        # Default construct using all args
        pass

    @staticmethod
    with_owner(name):
        return Cheese(0, None, name)
```

Use it like so:

```
cheddar = Cheese(0, None, None)
owned_cheddar = Cheese.with_owner('MickeyMouse')
```

Note that using static methods is kind of inflexible for your application; it is better used when constructing objects from different data structures, like `.from_dict(...)`, `.from_csv(...)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for these examples! I think what I wanted is not really possible right now, so I re-asked the question in a way to maybe make a change in a future version of python